# How to get the size of each value of a hash

Tags: ruby, hash, arrays

I have a hash, each value is an array.

I want to build a new array containing the size of each value/array.

Example:

the hash

```
{"A"=>["1", "2", "3"], "B"=>["b", "toto"]}
```

the result

```
[3, 2]
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
some_hash.values.map { |v| v.size }
```

and in 1.9, I believe you can do:

```
some_hash.values.map(&:size)
```

Comment: I think you can skip values and just do `some_hash.map {|k,v| v.size }`

Comment: @kejadlen: yeah I think I like your syntax the best of all

Comment: BTW: it is customary to use `_` as the name for a variable that is used solely for destructuring bind but doesn't actually get used. (This goes back to languages with pattern matching such as Haskell, ML or Scala, where `_` is actually a special wildcard pattern similar to `*` in the shell.) So, I would either use `some_hash.values.map(&:size)` or `some_hash.map {|_, v| v.size }`. The latter only in non-Rails Ruby 1.8.6, otherwise I would prefer the former, but that's just personal preference.

Comment: For clarity, I think `hash.values.map` is more appropriate. It's possible that `hash.map` is faster, but I do not think it is clearer. Unless this is a core (frequently executed) function, clear should trump fast.

Answer (score 2):

I would do:

```
h.collect{|v|v[1].size}
```